# AngularJS set values of multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi select dropdown that functions as appropriate when setting values, but once set, I need to display what has been selected in an update form. My values are stored in a DB (SharePoint) accessible over REST. Here is an example REST output with multiple IDs of my array:

```
"CatId": [
    18,
    80,
    84
],
```

Here is my select function, including retrieving the variable from REST:

```
var currentCatValue = results.CatId;

 $scope.categoryValues = [];

    appCatList.query(function (categorydata) {
        var categoryValues = categorydata.value; // Data is within an object of "value", so this pushes the server side array into the $scope array

        // Foreach type, push values into types array
        angular.forEach(categoryValues, function (categoryvalue, categorykey) {

            $scope.categoryValues.push({
                label: categoryvalue.Title,
                value: categoryvalue.ID,
            });
        })
        var currentDetailIndex = $scope.categoryValues.map(function (e) { return e.value; }).indexOf(currentCatValue);
        $scope.vm.selectedCategory = $scope.categoryValues[currentDetailIndex];
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Event_Cat" data-ng-model="vm.selectedCategory"
                                data-ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in categoryValues | orderBy:'label'" required>
                            <option style="display:none" value="">Select a Category</option>
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Using id (inspired by yvesmancera) in ng-model would greatly reduce the complexity - You don't need to pre-process your options and input array anymore, just plug it in and done!

```
<select multiple ng-model="currentCatValue" ng-options="opt.ID as opt.Title for opt in categoryValues">

$scope.currentCatValue = currentCatValue;
$scope.categoryValues = categoryValues;
```

Note: normally we would pre-populate ng-options into an array to preserve the order of the options, if the original data is an object. But since you use orderBy, you can use the object directly as ng-options.

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/heqikonako/1/edit?html,js,output)

---

**Outdated:**

You need to point to the same object in ng-options for them to get selected on load.

```
$scope.categoryValues = [];
$scope.vm.selectedCategory = [];

angular.forEach(categoryValues, function (categoryvalue, categorykey) {
    var category = {
        label: categoryvalue.Title,
        value: categoryvalue.ID,
    }      

    $scope.categoryValues.push(category);

    if (currentCatValue.indexOf(parseInt(category.value)) != -1) {
        $scope.vm.selectedCategory.push(category);
    }
});
```

Comment: No such luck. It is stating: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference

Comment: You'll need to initialize the arrays before using push

Comment: Maybe using id in selected by yvesmancera would suits you more. You can also try using the raw input as ng-model and see whether it works.

Comment: Does using id in this fashion remove the need to detect the array index?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, it removes the need of pre-populate ng-model

Comment: Ah that makes sense. It is still getting the index.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your ng-options to something like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Event_Cat" data-ng-model="vm.selectedCategory" data-ng-options="opt.id as opt.label for opt in categoryValues | orderBy:'label'" required>
      <option style="display:none" value="">Select a Category</option>
</select>
```

And make this line change in your controller:

```
$scope.vm.selectedCategory = $scope.categoryValues[currentDetailIndex].id;
```

**Edit for multiple selection:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="Event_Cat" data-ng-model="selectedCategoriesIds" data-ng-options="opt.id as opt.label for opt in categoryValues | orderBy:'label'" required multiple>
      <option style="display:none" value="">Select a Category</option>
</select>
```

In your controller, add the items you want selected to $scope.selectedCategoriesIds e.g.:

```
$scope.selectedCategoriesIds = [];
$scope.selectedCategoriesIds.push('18');
$scope.selectedCategoriesIds.push('80');
```

Comment: That was closer, but it only selects one value in the dropdown